# Universal mantra of all mantras for attaining the highest level of God realization?

Tags: mantras, moksha, meditation

There are a lot of mantras in our scriptures. Some of these mantras are used to invoke a particular deity, activity or a life-event. Some are mantras for longevity, some for knowledge, immortality, liberation and so on. Some of the highly notable mantras are Gayatri mantra, Hare Krishna Mahamantra and 'Om Namo Bhagavate Vasudevaya' which was used by Dhruva during his penance.

**Gayatri Mantra**

> ॐ भूर्भुवस्व: | तत्सवितुर्वरेण्यम् | भर्गो देवस्य धीमहि | धियो यो न: प्रचोदयात्
>
> Oṁ Bhūr Bhuva~Swah' Tat Savitur varenyam bhargo devasya dhīmahi dhiyo yo naḥ prachodayāt
>
> "Let us meditate on that excellent glory of the divine Light (Vivifier, Sun). May he stimulate our understandings (knowledge, intellectual illumination).

**Hare Krishna Mantra**

> हरे कृष्ण हरे कृष्ण कृष्ण कृष्ण हरे हरे | हरे रामा हरे रामा रामा रामा हरे हरे ||
>
> Hare kṛṣṇa hare kṛṣṇa kṛṣṇa kṛṣṇa hare hare | Hare rāma hare rāma rāma rāma hare hare
>
> "Oh energy of the Lord, please engage me in the loving service of Lord Krishna."

**Om Namo Bhagavate Vasudevaya**

> ॐ नमो भगवते वासुदेवाय
>
> Om Namo Bhagavate Vasudevaya
>
> "O my Lord, Śrī Kṛṣṇa, son of Vasudeva, O all-pervading Personality of Godhead, I offer my respectful obeisances unto You."

However, is there **one universal Mantra / Mahamantra** which can be chanted by a devotee, irrespective of his Varna, gotra, phase of life which takes him to the highest realm of God realization? Is it one of the above mantras?

Comment: The translation of 1st and 2nd mantra looks same; you may want to edit the question. I think Gayatri mantra is the one which you are asking.

Comment: Updated. @iammilind thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The Lord God's Name is the best mantra for liberation. Simply repeat the name of your Ishta Deva with firm faith and devotion and one is sure to attain liberation

Comment: But, then isn't this being specific? I mean `Ishta Deva` are subjective to everyone. I understand that you can still reach the "source" **through a medium (in this case Ishta Deva)**. But, what I'm specifically asking for is a mantra to directly reach the "source", the unmanifested form, the absolute 'God'.

Comment: Oh Ok. I guess AUM is said to be a mantra that is pure vibration and not based on any form. But IMHO there is no need for difference. The 'source, unmanifested' is no different from the Ishta Deva. The Ishta Deva is called Saguna Brahman, while the unmanifest is called Nirguna Brahman. Due to our own mind being afflicted with Gunas, we attribute gunas to That Being who is actually without it. Thus the same Brahman, assumes as it were, some attributes due to the devotion of the Devotee. upon constant chanting these 'attributes' disappear and one becomes one with the Deity.

Comment: A word of caution. Any mantra , especially one which contains bijaksharas like om etc. MUST be obtained from a learned guru through the prescribed process of initiation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I upvoted [SwamiVishwananda's answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8338/1049), but not 100% convinced. **ॐ** is more of a sound vibration than a mantra.
Hence, I would extend it to below 2 mantras from Bhagavad Gita:

### 1. [Gayatri Mantra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gayatri_Mantra)

```
ॐ भूर्भुवः॒ स्वः ।
तत्स॑वि॒तुर्वरे॑ण्यं॒
भर्गो॑ दे॒वस्य॑ धीमहि ।
धियो॒ यो नः॑ प्रचो॒दया॑त् ॥
```

**Meaning**: *We meditate on the glory of that being who has produced this universe; May he enlighten our minds.* (as translated by Swami Vivekananda)

This mantra is the form of God itself.

[BG 10.35](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/10/35)

> Of the hymns in the Sāma Veda I am the Bṛhat-sāma, and of poetry I am
>   the **Gāyatrī**. Of months I am Mārgaśīrṣa [November-December], and of
>   seasons I am ﬂower-bearing spring.

### 2. [Aum Tat Sat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om_Tat_Sat)

```
ॐ तत् सत्
```

**Meaning**: *There is only 1 lord and truth*.
Some people suggest that *Hari Aum Tat Sat* is the version for Kaliyuga.

According to Krishna, this mantra existed from the very origination.

[BG 17.23](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/17/23)

> From the beginning of creation, the three words **oṁ tat sat** were used
>   to indicate the Supreme Absolute Truth. These three symbolic
>   representations were used by brāhmaṇas while chanting the hymns of the
>   Vedas and during sacriﬁces for the satisfaction of the Supreme.

Comment: Very well put, iammilind! I wasn't too convinced about it but, as many have said here that 'Om' is in itself a mantra, I accepted it as a somewhat satisfactory answer. Thank you for putting the effort in answering my question. I think, your answer is more convincing and therefore I'll be marking it as such.

Answer (score 7):

Swami Vivekananda said (*Complete Works* V7 p 62, also here under *Inspired Talks*, *Sunday July 21* - http://cwsv.belurmath.org/volume_7/vol_7_frame.htm):

> Repeating the ***ॐ(Aum)*** continually is the only true worship. It is not a word, it is God Himself.

The Vedas say that the Om (pronounced AUM, and better represented as AUM) is the sound (vibration) that was first projected out of Brahman. It is from this initial vibration that the entire universe is created. As it is the manifestation of Brahman in the universe it is equated with Brahman. It is referred to as such throughout many many places in the Vedas. As it is equated with Brahman, both literally and figuratively, prayers are always started by first pronouncing AUM. Some examples are first the *Prasna Upanishad* fifth chapter. A few verses from this chapter:

> He replied: O Satyakama, the syllable AUM is the Supreme Brahman [Nirguna Brahman] and also the other Brahman [Saguna Brahman]. Therefore he who knows it attains, with its support, the one or the other.
>
> Again, he who meditates on the Highest Person [Saguna Brahman] through this syllable AUM consisting of three letters, becomes united with the effulgent sun. As a snake is freed from its skin, even so he is freed from sin.
>
> ...And also through the syllable AUM he realizes that which is tranquil, free from decay, death, and fear, and which is the Highest.

and the *Mandukya Upanishad* (I.) says:

> Harih AUM! AUM, the word, is all this [i.e. the whole universe]. A clear explanation of it is as follows: All that is past, present, and future is, indeed, AUM. And whatever else there is, beyond the three-fold division of time--that also is truly AUM.

other examples include *Katha Upanishad* (I. ii. 15) "It is AUM"; Katha Upanishad (I. ii. 17) "This AUM is the best support"; *Taittiriya Upanishad* (I. viii. 1) "AUM this word is Brahman."

Comment: Thank you for the Great answer Swamiji, it may be of interest to note that Sri Krishna says in the Gita 'The one who repeats constantly the single syllable OM, merges in Me' :) 8:13. :)

Comment: @sai yes there is no dearth of references and just needed to cutoff references at some point. There are several Gita references.

Answer (score 1):

OM has already been mentioned in the answers. I am adding one more reference in support of OM.

> The syllable OM is the root from which the Vedas have sprung. (Every
>   rite, therefore, should commence with the utterance of that syllable
>   of vast import). Of him who has uttered for him the syllables Om,
>   Namas, Swaha, Svadha, and Vashat, and who has according to the extent
>   of his ability, performed sacrifices, and other rites, there is no
>   fear in respect of next life in all the three worlds

.
Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CCLXVIII

Answer (score 0):

श्रीरामनामामृतमन्त्रबीजं संजीवनी चेन्मसि प्रविष्टा ।

हालाहले वा प्रलयानलं वा मृत्योर्मुखं वा विशतां कुतोभिः ॥

- (आनन्दरामायण, जन्मकाण्ड ६।४३)
- 'भगवान् श्रीरामका नाम सम्पूर्ण मन्त्रोंका बीज मूल है, वह मेरे सर्वाङ्गमें पूर्णतः प्रविष्ट हो चुका है, अतः हालाहल विष हो, प्रलयानल-ज्वाला हो या मृत्युमुख ही क्यों न हो मुझे इनका किंचित् भी भय नहीं है।' यह कहते हुए शिवजी 'विष'-पान कर गये। वह विष अमृत बन गया। उसी दिनसे उनका नाम 'नीलकण्ठ' पड़ गया। और सब देव हैं, शिवजी 'महादेव' बन गये।

Shri Ram naam is beej of all vedic and puranic mantras and is the only universal mantra of all mantras for greatest realisation of bhagwan.

Answer (score 0):

Ram Naam is the only name in which the whole world is contained, 7 crore Mahamantras have been told in the scriptures, whose soul is called Ram Naam. That is why renouncing all calamities, just chant the name of Ram.Lord Shri Krishna Himself singing the glory of Shri Ram Naam says:~

अथ श्रीपद्मपुराण वर्णित रामनामामृत स्त्रोत श्रीकृष्ण अर्जुन संवाद~

अर्जुन उवाच~

१)
भुक्तिमुक्तिप्रदातृणां सर्वकामफलप्रदं ।
सर्वसिद्धिकरानन्त नमस्तुभ्यं जनार्दन ॥

अर्थ:~ सभी भोग और मुक्ति के फल दाता, सभी कर्मों का फल देने वाले, सभी कार्य को सिद्ध करने वाले जनार्दन मैं आपको नमन करता हूं।

२)
यं कृत्वा श्री जगन्नाथ मानवा यान्ति सद्गतिम् ।
ममोपरि कृपां कृत्वा तत्त्वं ब्रहिमुखालयम्।।

अर्थ:~हे श्रीजगन्नाथ! मनुष्य ऐसा क्या करें कि उसे अंत में सद्गति हो? वह तत्व क्या है? मेरे पर कृपा करके अपने ब्रह्ममुख से बताइए।

श्रीकृष्ण उवाच~

१)
यदि पृच्छसि कौन्तेय सत्यं सत्यं वदाम्यहम् ।
लोकानान्तु हितातार्थाय इह लोके परत्र च ॥

अर्थ:~ हे कुंती पुत्र! यदि तुम मुझसे पूछते हो तो मैं सत्य सत्य बताता हूं, इस लोक और परलोक में हित करने वाला क्या है।

२)
रामनाम सदा पुण्यं नित्यं पठति यो नरः ।
अपुत्रो लभते पुत्रं सर्वकामफलप्रदम् ॥

अर्थ:~श्रीराम का नाम सदा पुण्य करने वाला नाम है, जो मनुष्य इसका नित्य पाठ करता है उसे पुत्र लाभ मिलता है और सभी कामनाएं पूर्ण होती है।

३)
मङ्गलानि गृहे तस्य सर्वसौख्यानि भारत।
अहोरात्रं च येनोक्तं राम इत्यक्षरद्वयम्।।

अर्थ:~हे भारत! उसके घर में सभी प्रकार के सुख और मंगल विराजित हो जाते हैं, जिसने दिन-रात श्रीराम नाम के दो अक्षरों का उच्चारण कर लिया।

४)
गङ्गा सरस्वती रेवा यमुना सिन्धु पुष्करे।
केदारेतूदकं पीतं राम इत्यक्षरद्वयम् ॥

अर्थ~जिसने श्रीरामनाम के इन दो अक्षरों का उच्चारण कर लिया उसने श्रीगंगा, सरस्वती, रेवा, यमुना, सिंधु, पुष्कर, केदारनाथ आदि सभी तीर्थों का स्नान, जलपान कर लिया।

५)
अतिथेः पोषणं चैव सर्व तीर्थावगाहनम् ।
सर्वपुण्यं समाप्नोति रामनाम प्रसादतः ।।

अर्थ:~उसने अतिथियों का पोषण कर लिया, सभी तीर्थों में स्नान आदि कर लिया, उसने सभी पुण्य कर्म कर लिए जिसने श्रीराम नाम का उच्चारण कर लिया।

६)
सूर्यपर्व कुरुक्षेत्रे कार्तिक्यां स्वामि दर्शने।
कृपापात्रेण वै लब्धं येनोक्तमक्षरद्वयम्।।

अर्थ:~उसने सूर्य ग्रहण के समय कुरुक्षेत्र में स्नान कर लिया और कार्तिक पूर्णिमा में कार्तिक जी का दर्शन करके कृपा प्राप्त कर ली जिसने श्रीराम नाम का उच्चारण कर लिया।

७)
न गंङ्गा न गया काशी नर्मदा चैव पुष्करम् ।
सदृशं रामनाम्नस्तु न भवन्ति कदाचन।।

अर्थ:~ ना तो गंगा, गया, काशी, प्रयाग, पुष्कर, नर्मदादिक इन सब में कोई भी श्रीराम नाम की महिमा के समक्ष नहीं हो सकते।

८)
येन दत्तं हुतं तप्तं सदा विष्णुः समर्चितः।
जिह्वाग्रे वर्तते यस्य राम इत्यक्षरद्वयम्।।

अर्थ:~उसने भांति-भांति के हवन, दान, तप और विष्णु भगवान की आराधना कर ली, जिसकी जिह्वा के अग्रभाग पर श्रीराम नाम के दो अक्षर विराजित हो गए।

९)
माघस्नानं कृतं येन गयायां पिण्डपातनम् ।
सर्वकृत्यं कृतं तेन येनोक्तं रामनामकम्।।

अर्थ:~ उसने प्रयागजी में माघ का स्नान कर लिया, गयाजी में पिंडदान कर लिया उसने अपने सभी कार्यों को पूर्ण कर लिया जिसने श्रीराम नाम का उच्चारण कर लिया।

१०)
प्रायश्चित्तं कृतं तेन महापातकनाशनम् ।
तपस्तप्तं च येनोक्तं राम इत्यक्षरद्वयम् ।।

अर्थ~उसने अपने सभी महापापों का नाश करके प्रायश्चित कर लिया और तपस्या पूर्ण कर ली जिसने श्रीराम नाम के दो अक्षर का उच्चारण कर लिया।

११)
चत्वारः पठिता वेदास्सर्वे यज्ञाश्च याजिताः ।
त्रिलोकी मोचिता तेन राम इत्यक्षरद्वयम् ।।

अर्थ~उसने चारों वेदों का सांगोपांग पाठ कर लिया सभी यज्ञ आदि कर्म कर लिए उसने तीनों लोगों को तार दिया जिसने श्रीराम नाम के दो अक्षर का पाठ कर लिया।

१२)
भूतले सर्व तीर्थानि आसमुद्रसरांसि च।
सेवितानि च येनोक्तं राम इत्यक्षरद्वयम् ।।

अर्थ~उसने भूतल पर सभी तीर्थ, समुद्र, सरोवर आदि का सेवन कर लिया जिसने श्रीराम नाम के दो अक्षरों का जाप कर लिया।

अर्जुन उवाच~

१)
यदा म्लेच्छमयी पृथ्वी भविष्यति कलौयुगे ।
किं करिष्यति लोकोऽयं पतितो रौरवालये ।।

अर्थ~भविष्य में कलयुग आने पर पूरी पृथ्वी मलेच्छ मयी हो जाएगी इसका स्वरूप रौ-रौ नर्क की भांति हो जाएगा तब जीव कौन सा साधन करके परम पद पाएगा?

श्रीकृष्ण उवाच~

१)
न सन्देहस्त्वया काय्र्यो न वक्तव्यं पुनः पुनः ।
पापी भवति धर्मात्मा रामनाम प्रभावतः ।।

अर्थ~यह संदेह करने योग्य नहीं है, जैसे संदेह व्यर्थ है वैसे बार-बार वक्तव्य देना भी व्यर्थ है। कैसा भी पापी हो श्रीराम नाम के प्रभाव से वह धर्मात्मा हो जाता है

२)
न म्लेच्छस्पर्शनात्तस्य पापं भवति देहिनः ।
तस्मात्प्रमुच्यते जन्तुर्यस्मरेद्रामद्वचत्तरम् ।।

अर्थ~उसे मलेच्छ के स्पर्श का भी पाप नहीं होता, मलेच्छ संबंधित पाप भी छूट जाते हैं जो श्रीराम नाम के दो अक्षरों का जाप करते हैं।

३)
रामस्तत्वमधीयानः श्रद्धाभक्तिसमन्वितः।
कुलायुतं समुद्धृत्य रामलोके महीयते ।।

अर्थ~जो श्रीराम से संबंध रखने वाले स्त्रोत का पाठ करते हैं तथा जिनकी भक्ति, विश्वास और श्रद्धा श्रीराम में सुदृढ़ है। वह लोग अपने दस हज़ार पीढ़ियों का उद्धार करके श्रीराम के लोक में पूजित होते है।

४)
रामनामामृतं स्तोत्रं सायं प्रातः पठेन्नरः ।
गोघ्नः स्त्रीबालघाती च सर्व पापैः प्रमुच्यते ।।

अर्थ~जो सुबह शाम इस रामनामामृत स्त्रोत का पाठ करते हैं वे गौ हत्या, स्त्री और बच्चों को हानि पहुंचाने वाले पाप से भी बच कर मुक्त हो जाते हैं।

(इति श्रीपद्मपुराणे रामनामामृत स्त्रोते श्रीकृष्ण अर्जुन संवादे संपूर्णम्)